# Alternative to complex else if ladders

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a function that returns a value called `user_id`. But there are many conditions to be checked.

condition 1: check service variable

condition 2: If no, get `user_id` from localstorage

condition 3: If no, get `firebase_uid` from localstorage, and call function `findUserId(firebase_uid)` which will return `user_id`

condition 4: if no, get `uid` from firebase and call `findUserId(uid)`

here is the code.

```
export class UserService {

  user_id : any;
  firebase_uid: any;
  id: any;

returnUser_id() {

    if(this.user_id) {

      return this.user_id
    }

    else {
      this.storageService.get('user_id').then(val =>{
        if(val) {
          this.user_id =val
          return this.user_id
        }

        else {
          this.storageService.get('firebase_uid').then(value =>{
            if(value) {
              this.firebase_uid = value

              this.findUserId(this.firebase_uid).subscribe(q =>{
                console.log(q)
                this.id = q;
                for(let i =0; i<this.id.length;i++) {
                  this.user_id = this.id[i].id

                  return this.user_id

                }


                this.storageService.set('user_id', this.user_id ).then(result => {
                  console.log('Data is saved');
                  }).catch(e => {
                  console.log("error: " + e);
                  });


              })

            }
            else { 
              this.afauth.authState.subscribe(user =>{
                if(user) {
                  this.firebase_uid = user.uid; 


                  this.storageService.set('firebase_uid', this.firebase_uid ).then(result => {
                    console.log('Data is saved');
                    }).catch(e => {
                    console.log("error: " + e);
                    });


                    this.findUserId(this.firebase_uid).subscribe(data =>{
                      this.id = data;

                      for(let i = 0 ;i<this.id.length; i++ ){
                        this.user_id = this.id[i].id
                        return this.user_id
                      }

                      this.storageService.set('user_id', this.user_id ).then(result => {
                        console.log('Data is saved');
                        }).catch(e => {
                        console.log("error: " + e);
                        });
                    })
                }
              })
            }


          }).catch(err =>{
            console.log(err)
          })
        }
      }).catch(err =>{
        console.log(err)
      })
    }

  }

}
```

findUserId function

```
findUserId(uid): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get<User[]>(this.user_url + 'users?filter[fields][id]=true&filter[where][firebase_uid]=' +uid )

}
```

This code is so complex and difficult to understand. Is there any alternative to traditional if else statements.

Thank you in advance

Comment: If the code works this is better suited for the codereview stackexchange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some repeatable code, so we can move repeatable code into method and reuse it. Moreover we can simplify our code [using async keywords](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

```
if(this.user_id)   
    return this.user_id;
else {
    let user_id = await this.storageService.get('user_id');
    if (user_id)  
        return user_id;
    else {
        let firebase_uid = await this.storageService.get('firebase_uid');
        if (firebase_uid) {
            await reusableFindUserId(firebase_uid);

            if (this.user_id)
                await setStorageService();
        }        
        else { 
            let user = await this.afauth.authState();
            if (user) {
                this.firebase_uid = user.uid;
                await reusableFindUserId(firebase_uid);

                if (this.user_id)
                    await setStorageService();
            }
        })
      }
    }
}
```

and reusable methods:

```
async reusableFindUserId(firebase_uid){
    this.id = await this.findUserId(firebase_uid);
    for(let i =0; i<this.id.length;i++) {
        this.user_id = this.id[i].id;
        return this.user_id;
    }
}

async setStorageService() {
    return await this.storageService.set('user_id', this.user_id );
}
```

Comment: I like this answer because, it will create more readable code, and after that part is refactored, other methods can be used in which if else statements can be updated altogether

Comment: Thank you @StepUp for your answer. But I have a small problem. Even though we have used  await for findUserId() and setStorageService(), when user_id is not stored in localstorage(means it is null), it is storing user_id as null in localstorage. Thus it can't be accessed on other pages

Comment: @StepUp When we try to access the code on another page using code                      let x = await this.userService.returnUser_id()
    console.log("from cart " + x)                                                                                             It runs well when user_id is got from localstorage but when our code enters in findUserId() function , the value on the page (x) goes undefined because we are waiting for the main function and not for findUserId() . Although we are awaiting for findUserId() in our main function, the value on our page is getting undefined

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of this else, because you return in the if-block above. If you don't return, the remaining code will be executed.
You can go through the hole function and check if the elses are necessary. If you return, you don't need an else :)

Another point is, you can extract some parts of the code into dedicated functions. Your main function will be much cleaner and shorter.

```
if(val) {
      this.user_id =val
      return this.user_id
    }
// No need for the else...
else {
    ....
}
```